# why no error when use subprocess.check_output args in sequence

Tags: python, subprocess

I use python2.7

when I use subprocess.check_output,The result is correct,There is no file aaa

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(['ls','-l','aaa'])
ls: cannot access aaa: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 576, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ls', '-l', 'aaa']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

but when  I add shell=True

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(['ls','-l','aaa'],shell=True)
'test_multiprocess.py\ntest_threading.py\n'
```

The result is wrong,who can help me ,tell me why ,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very high-level explanation.

when `shell=False` is set (which is the default value), there is no system shell started up, so the first argument must be a path to an executable file and if `shell=True` means system shell (e.g.:  `\bin\sh`) will first spin up.

So basically when `shell=False` it's `subprocess.check_output(['ls','-l','aaa'])` and when you pass `shell=True` you could pass the cmd as follow `subprocess.check_output('ls -l aaa',shell=True)`

If `shell=True` and you pass command line arguments as a list only first element of the list will be executed and the rest will be ignored or would change `sh` behavior if it contains valid shell arguments.

```py
subprocess.check_output(args, *, stdin=None, stderr=None, shell=False, cwd=None, encoding=None, errors=None, universal_newlines=None, timeout=None, text=None, **other_popen_kwargs)
```

- `shell=False`, `args[:]` is a command line to execute
- `shell=True`, `args[0]` is a command line to execute and `args[1:]` are arguments to sh.